# Как создать универсальный класс

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста! Я в DataSet ResultData гружу данные из БД. А затем выбираю их в массив, который потом прикручиваю к комбобоксу в качестве источника данных. Массив содержит экземпляры класса ClData. В данном случае, я знаю какие столбцы я выдираю из БД. Вопрос. Как мне лучше сделать этот класс ClData и прикручивать к комбобоксу массив, Если например, я не знаю какие столбцы находятся в БД, но знаю их количество? То есть как создать некий универсальный класс или метод, который берет данные из БД, делает из них массив и прикрепляет его к комбобоксу?

```
List<ClData> ggg=new List<ClData>(){};
        if(resultSelect!=null)
           {
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSelect.ResultData.Rows.Count; i++) {
            ggg.Add(new ClData(resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(),resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString(),resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString()));
        }

_cmb_faculty_kaf.DisplayMember="faculty";
        _cmb_faculty_kaf.ValueMember="code_record";
        _cmb_faculty_kaf.DataSource=ggg;
```

Сам класс

```
public  class ClData
{
    public ClData(string Faculty,string Name_shem,string Code_record)
    {
        name_shem=Name_shem;
        code_record=Code_record;
            faculty=Faculty;
    }
    public  string name_shem{ get; set; }
    public string faculty{ get; set; }
    public string code_record{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `WPF` или `WinForms`? И там и там есть комбобокс. Добавьте нужный тег.

Comment: В зависимости что тебе нужно вывести, но общий способ выглядит так. Все поля одной записи собираешь в одну строку. Склеиваешь такие строки в массив и прикрепляешь к комбоксу.

Comment: @adrug через биндинг более правильно. Особенно если простой List<T> заменить на BindingList<T>, тогда комбобокс еще и обновляться будет автоматом, при обновлении списка сущностей. Для WPF этот вариант немного проще чем для WinForms, но возможен и там, и там.